# Oracle include NULL containing rows when compared string is zero length

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am building a function in Oracle where I would like to return a set of results based on input parameters.

Minimal select query

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE FIRSTNAME LIKE '%' || P_FIRSTNAME || '%';
```

where P_FIRSTNAME is a parameter coming from the function call.

This works mostly fine, however in case the incoming parameter is an empty string, I would like the select clause to also return rows where FIRSTNAME is NULL. The real query will have more conditions in the where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another condition:

```
select *
from employees
where  :p_firstname is null                      --> this
  or firstname like '%' || :p_firstname ||'%';
```

Comment: Ok, this didn't occur to me, thx. Do I even need to check for firstname null-ness then? Wouldn't this be more efficient? 
select *
from employees
where  :p_firstname is null or firstname like '%' || :p_firstname ||'%' ;

Comment: That would be OK.